# Linq Expression Tree OrderByDescending with custom comparer

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, expression-trees

As the title says I'm trying to build an expression tree for source.OrderByDescending(this source, expression, comparer)

This is my code for generating the expression tree:

```
var orderByDescendingMethod = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).First(m => m.Name == "OrderByDescending" && m.GetParameters().Count() == 3).MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Books), typeof(string));
var comparer = Expression.New(typeof(NumericStringComparer));
var orderByFilter = GenerateOrderByPropertyExpression<string>(propertyName);
var comparison = Expression.Call(orderByDescendingMethod, Expression.Constant(books), orderByFilter, comparer);

return Expression.Lambda(comparison);
```

And the GenerateOrderByPropertyExpression method:

```
private static Expression<Func<Books, T>> GenerateOrderByPropertyExpression<T>(string propertyName)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Books), "b");
    var property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyName);
    var toStringMethod = typeof(object).GetMethod("ToString");
    var objectString = Expression.Call(property, toStringMethod);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<Books, T>>(objectString, parameter);
}
```

But whenever I call `lambda.Compile().DynamicInvoke();` and inspect the result, I get the following error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable`1[DataAccess.Plusbog.Books] OrderByDescending[Books,String](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[DataAccess.Plusbog.Books], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[DataAccess.Plusbog.Books,System.String]], System.Collections.Generic.IComparer`1[System.String])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I feel like I'm pretty close.

Comment: Entity framework can't work with your custom comparer `NumericStringComparer`, hence "can't be translated into a store expression".

Comment: [Supported and Unsupported LINQ Methods (LINQ to Entities)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550(v=vs.110).aspx) - **Ordering Methods:** *Most of the LINQ ordering methods are supported in LINQ to Entities, **with the exception of those that accept an IComparer<T>**, because the comparer cannot be translated to the data source.*

Comment: Of course. Big oversight on my part. Thanks!

Comment: @IvanStoev I think you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An excerpt from the [Supported and Unsupported LINQ Methods (LINQ to Entities)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550(v=vs.110).aspx) - **Ordering Methods** section:

> Most of the LINQ ordering methods are supported in LINQ to Entities, **with the exception of those that accept an IComparer<T>**, because the comparer cannot be translated to the data source.